# how remove a character+ all white spaces around it?

Tags: pyspark

How I can remove all spaces and `&` from text?

```
col1
H&M
H & M
H  &  M
H &M
H& M
```

output

```
col1
HM
HM
HM
HM
HM
```

Help me to fix the following code or give me new one:

```
df.withColumn('col1', F.regexp_replace("col1", "&", ""))
```

Also how I can get `''` if there is space between characters and words and `' '` if there is no white space between character and words.

```
col1
H&M
H & M
H  &  M
H &M
H& M
```

output

```
col1
H M
H M
H M
H M
H M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all characters except alphabets

`df = df.withColumn('col1',regexp_replace('col1','[^A-Z]','')).show()`

Comment: is there any way i replace by `''` if there is space between characters and words (like `H & M`)and replace by `' '` (one white space) if there is no space between character and words? like this `H&M`

Comment: No clear on what you want, example input, output?

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: Try `df.withColumn('col1',regexp_replace(regexp_replace('col1','\s',''),'\&',' ')).show()`